# How do I set the height of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox on a form, and its default height is 21. How do I change it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

ComboBox auto-sizes to fit the font.  Turning that off is not an option.  If you want it bigger then give it a bigger font.

Comment: To adjust the height to the number of items, see the property DropDownHeight.

Answer (score 18):

Set the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawVariable`.  However customization of the ComboBox leads to other issues.  See this link for a tutorial on how to do this completely:

<s>http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/09/listbox-control-in-c/</s>

`OwnerDrawVariable` sample code here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Once that's done, you need to set the `ItemHeight` property of the combobox to set the effective height of the combobox.

Comment: Your link no longer works, could you summarise the contents?

Comment: @AnyaHope: I updated to the MSDN link which contains some sample code. Set up a project using the sample code, supplement the sample by adding `ItemHeight` as I described, and you should be good.

Answer (score 12):

Just as another option, if you'd like to increase the height of the `ComboBox` without increasing the font size or having to worry about drawing everything yourself, you can use a simple Win32 API call to increase the height like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Win32ComboBoxHeightExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
        private const Int32 CB_SETITEMHEIGHT = 0x153;

        private void SetComboBoxHeight(IntPtr comboBoxHandle, Int32 comboBoxDesiredHeight)
        {
            SendMessage(comboBoxHandle, CB_SETITEMHEIGHT, -1, comboBoxDesiredHeight);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetComboBoxHeight(comboBox1.Handle, 150);
            comboBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: No effect. Running Windows 10 64-bit.  It just made the combobox look non-modern almost as if in owner-drawn mode.

Comment: Worked for me.  Win 10 64-bit, Any CPU build.  I did have to be careful on the timing...I couldn't run it in the constructor of my custom ComboBox control, I used the first time "DrawItem" was called to do it.  Also, `DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable`

Comment: Worked for me on Win 10 64-bit as well. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me on Win 10 64-bit, but ONLY after i set it's height values to something less than 300.

Answer (score 5):

To do this, you need to set the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawVariable` or `OwnerDrawFixed` and manually draw your items. This can be done with a pretty simple class.

This example will allow you to use the `ItemHeight` property of the ComboBox regardless of font size. I threw in an bonus property `TextAlign` which will also allow you to center the items.

One thing worth mentioning is, you must set `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` for the selected item to respect our customizations.

```
// The standard combo box height is determined by the font. This means, if you want a large text box, you must use a large font.
// In our class, ItemHeight will now determine the height of the combobox with no respect to the combobox font.
// TextAlign can be used to align the text in the ComboBox
class UKComboBox : ComboBox
{

    private StringAlignment _textAlign = StringAlignment.Center;
    [Description("String Alignment")]
    [Category("CustomFonts")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(StringAlignment))]
    public StringAlignment TextAlign
    {
        get { return _textAlign; }
        set
        {
            _textAlign = value;
        }
    }

    private int _textYOffset = 0;
    [Description("When using a non-centered TextAlign, you may want to use TextYOffset to manually center the Item text.")]
    [Category("CustomFonts")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(int))]
    public int TextYOffset
    {
        get { return _textYOffset; }
        set
        {
            _textYOffset = value;
        }
    }


    public UKComboBox()
    {
            // Set OwnerDrawVariable to indicate we will manually draw all elements.
            this.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
            // DropDownList style required for selected item to respect our DrawItem customizations.
            this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            // Hook into our DrawItem & MeasureItem events
            this.DrawItem +=
                new DrawItemEventHandler(ComboBox_DrawItem);
            this.MeasureItem +=
                new MeasureItemEventHandler(ComboBox_MeasureItem);

    }

    // Allow Combo Box to center aligned and manually draw our items
    private void ComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {


        // Draw the background
        e.DrawBackground();

        // Draw the items
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            // Set the string format to our desired format (Center, Near, Far)
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = _textAlign;
            sf.Alignment = _textAlign;

            // Set the brush the same as our ForeColour
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);

            // If this item is selected, draw the highlight
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                brush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;

            // Draw our string including our offset.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), this.Font, brush, 
                new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + _textYOffset, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height), sf);
        }

    }


    // If you set the Draw property to DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable, 
    // you must handle the MeasureItem event. This event handler 
    // will set the height and width of each item before it is drawn. 
    private void ComboBox_MeasureItem(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Custom heights per item index can be done here.
    }

}
```

Now we have full control over our font and height of the ComboBox separately. We no longer need to make a large font to size our ComboBox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to adjust to the number of items in the ComboBox you can change the value of the DropDownHeight as follows, given a List of items. I'm using 24 here as a "per item amount"; this is by no means fixed.

```
  comboBox1.DropDownHeight = SomeList.Count * 24;
```

Answer (score -1):

In code, a.Height should work. In the designer, go into the properties and look in Size->Height.

Alternatively, you can change the Font Size and the combo box will grow bigger to accomodate it, but I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score -1):

ComboBox has a property 'DropDownHeight' which can be changed either via the properties window of the combobox or programmatically. i.e.

```
public partial class EventTestForm : Form
{
    public EventTestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmbOwners.DropDownHeight = 100;
    }
```