# How to set combobox height manually

Tags: winforms, combobox

I tried to set the ComboBox height manually but the default height = 21 of the combobox was not changed when i try to set manually.

Height of the Combobox was set based on the font size of it. How to change the Combobox height manually.

I also tried the workaround from this link
[How do I set the height of a ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158004/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-a-combobox)

Comment: The accepted answer from Hans on that link: "ComboBox auto-sizes to fit the font. Turning that off is not an option. If you want it bigger then give it a bigger font."

Comment: Hi @Equalsk, I tried the WinAPI32 calls but it doesn't work. then how can i achieve my requirement? is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you tried to set the DrawMode to OwnerDrawVariable?

Comment: Hi @Ian I tried by setting DrawMode also, but it doen'w work