# how to modify height of Xamarin ComboBox dropdown inside stacklayout or grid

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, combobox

how to modify height dynamically, focus & unfocus events not working

```
   <combobox:ComboBox x:Name="ComboProduct"                                      
                      ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredProductList}"    Placeholder="Type 3 characters or more"
                SelectedItem="{Binding  Path=ProductInput,Mode=TwoWay}"  EntryDisplayPath="Name"     
                           TextChanged="ComboProduct_TextChanged" Visual="Material"  Focused="ComboProduct_Focused" Unfocused="ComboProduct_Unfocused"      >

                                    <combobox:ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="5,5,0,0"/>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>

                                    </combobox:ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </combobox:ComboBox>
```

Comment: Is this helps you ? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158004/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-a-combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158004/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-a-combobox)

Comment: Xamarin does not have a builtin ComboBox control, so it would be helpful if you tell us where you are getting yours from

Comment: From nuget package manager, there is a package called xamarin. Forms. Combobox