# How to automatically set height of Combo Box in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, autosize

I'm trying to fill cell in my TabView in C# .NET Framework 4.7.2 app with ComboBox as shown on the image below, but I can't figure how to fill it horizontally. Can you help me?

[combo shown here (image description of a problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgUJ4.png)

Comment: Did you mean vertically? Because the combobox in the picture does already fill the horizontal space

Comment: Also i think it is not possibly. The combobox does auto size its height to the choosen font.

Comment: Change DrawMode to one of the OwnerDraw values. Then you are able to change the ItemHeight that then also influences the Controls Height. Then have a closer look at how that really looks (presumably weird as i would expect for a combobox) and revert/actually painting yourself/live with how it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComboBox height is decided by the font size of it. To change the height you have to draw the complete ComboBox yourself by setting the `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawnVariable`. But this also means that you are now in-charge of everything of that ComboBox and introduces far more complexity.

Please refer to the Microsoft Learn Documentation on `ComboBox.DrawMode` property at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode?view=netframework-4.7.2 which contains the code example for doing it.

To do it automatically on Table Layout Panel after manually drawing the ComboBox you'll have to update the height each time the row height is updated. You can get the row height from [TableLayoutPanel.RowStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2) property.

Related: [c# - How do I set the height of a ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158004/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-a-combobox)

Comment: Seems the right answer but accepted in seconds? Fishy